# Windows Phone: How to stay in the Current page rather than navigating to another page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have two pages (MainPage and page1). when the user is in the page1, if the user press back key, following message should pop up : "Are you sure that you want to exit? "

Thus, if user press OK then it should navigate to another page, if the user press Cancel it should stay in the same page. Here is my Code:

This code is written in Page1.Xaml:

```
Protected override void OnBackKeyPrss(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
      MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.show("Are you sure that you want to exit?",
      "", MessageBoxButton.OkCancel);
      if(res==MessageBoxResult.OK)
      {
         App.Navigate("/mainpage.xaml");
      }
      else
      {
            //enter code here
      }

}
```

However, when I am pressing cancel it is still navigating to mainpage.xaml. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.Cancel = true;` to cancel back navigation.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Your code is looking messed up. I think you last page/back page is `mainpage.xaml` and in `OK` you are again navigating to this page. If this is the case then there is no need of navigating again you can use below code.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to exit?",
    "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (res != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;  //when pressed cancel don't go back
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the classic "Are you sure you want to quit?" message dialog, you need to override the `OnBackKeyPress` event and use yourown `MessageBox` in it :

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", 
                                           "Confirm exit action",
                                           MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (messageBoxResult != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        e.Cancel = true;
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

But I would like to point the navigation logic and why you're doing something wrong. If I understood correctly, `MainPage` is the first page which is shown when the app is launched and `Page1` is shown when navigating to it from `MainPage`.

When navigating backwards, instead of

<strike>`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`</strike>

(you didn't write like this, but at least this is what you should have written, with correct syntax but wrong logic)

should be done like this :

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

This is because while navigating within your app, there will be a `NavigationStack` (with the navigated pages) which will only have actions of `Push()`(Navigation forwards) instead of also `Pop()`(Navigation backwards).

For more navigation information in Windows Phone, [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx).